# Database Baselines

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am a SQL Server accidental DBA who has inherited a few database and am trying to set baselines thresholds to monitor these servers.

Does anyone know a good way to go about this?

What am looking to do is as follows: I want to capture the different metrics on each SQL Server instance so that when we are having issues I can always go back to the baseline and see where it varies. I want to make this my starting point for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baseline monitoring of SQL Server database varies on server configuration.

Yet here is some description you can go through:

[What should be monitored for baseline sql server performance](https://serverfault.com/questions/135138/what-should-be-monitored-for-baseline-sql-server-performance) (ServerFault)

Answer (score 5):

A few thoughts that may help you:

1. Collecting baselines in SQL Server is a good thing to do. You asked about baselines and also monitoring. There are several ways to collect a baseline. And monitoring is a different animal. From as simple as using Perfmon and `relog` to write to CSV files as Brent describes in this [post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2006/12/dba-101-using-perfmon-for-sql-performance-tuning/)  , to utilizing the PAL tool freely available on Codeplex as I blogged about [here](http://straightpathsql.com/archives/2016/07/create-sql-server-baseline/).  You can also look at using a tool like the [Management Data Warehouse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677306.aspx)
2. You also seemed to ask about monitoring. There are a lot of third party tools to help with this. Some are paid like SQL Sentry, Idera's tool, the Redgate SQL Monitor tool, etc. Some are freely available like the [Ops Server](https://github.com/opserver/Opserver) tool that Stack Overflow uses to monitor their environment.

   All of the monitoring tools are great for sure. I personally prefer SQL Sentry - it has a great baselining feature to have baselines by time periods, specific ranges, etc and then call them up and compare them.

You can also roll your own approach using a combination of SQL Server alerts, Management Data Warehouse and perfmon queries, but for a lot of reasons I'm a strong proponent of using something already created.